# Delete duplicates with different timestamps

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hey in SSMS I have this query:

```
SELECT MessageID
,MessageName
,DateTimeStamp
FROM faa_source_cleansed.message_meta_data
```

and have data in it like this:

| MessageID | MessageName | DateTimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MS_2srpuI0UBZC0yMe | Proxy_TEST | 2023-02-06 14:10:16.570 |
| MS_2srpuI0UBZC0yMe | Proxy_TEST | 2023-02-06 14:17:40.517 |
| MS_3DIRR1wBVXPrdlQ | Proxy_TEST | 2023-02-06 14:17:40.517 |
| MS_2srpuI0UBZC0yMe | Proxy_TEST | 2023-02-06 14:29:55.527 |
| MS_3DIRR1wBVXPrdlQ | Proxy_TEST | 2023-02-06 14:29:55.527 |
| MS_dpbKrzgBsXgVpTE | Proxy_TEST | 2023-02-06 14:29:55.527 |

I want to delete the rows where timestamp is greater than the smallest one.

So the result should be like this:

| MessageID | MessageName | DateTimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MS_2srpuI0UBZC0yMe | Proxy_TEST | 2023-02-06 14:10:16.570 |
| MS_3DIRR1wBVXPrdlQ | Proxy_TEST | 2023-02-06 14:17:40.517 |
| MS_dpbKrzgBsXgVpTE | Proxy_TEST | 2023-02-06 14:29:55.527 |

Comment: You say you "want to delete the rows"; do you *actually* mean `DELETE`?

Comment: @Larnu 
Yes I want to ```DELETE```

Comment: Does the MessageName matter?

Comment: Sample data like A, B and C is much easier to read than MS_2srpuI0UBZC0yMe, MS_2stpuI0UBZC0yMe and MS_2srpu10UBZC0yMe. Make it easy to assist you!